# Change order of xmlnamespace

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I was working on Xml serialization. My class is

```
[XmlRoot("urlset", Namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Url))] 
public class UrlSet
{


   [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
    public string xsiSchemaLocation = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" +
                                      "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd";
}
```

Tried adding

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlNameSpace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Output its giving to me is

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

I need to have

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

I also tried adding empty namespace, But that adds prefix q to every element in xml. I also want to know if that order really matters as I am going to submit generated sitemap to google

Any solutions?

Comment: Is your additional xmlns:xsi relevent or even valid? See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en and look for the section Sitemap extensions

Comment: Anyhow... I doubt the order will matter, xsi simply tells the interpreter that elements prefixed with xsi use that namespace.

Comment: @PaulZahra thanks but i have added it using XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlNameSpace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); and yes thats relevant and valid